# UserPolicy for Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I am trying to create a policy so that only admins can acces a page. I've already managed to get pundit to work in another controller, but for some reason this policy wont work.

I've created a controller: users_controller.rb which is as follows:

```
def index
  @user = current_user
  authorize @user
 end
end
```

I've created a Policy user_policy.rb which is:

```
  def initialize(current_user, record)
    @user = current_user
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    @user.admin?
  end
end
```

Any idea's what's going wrong?

Comment: How do you differentiate admin from users? Do you have a boolean attribute in users table?

Comment: That's right. I have a boolean attribute admin in my users table.

Comment: Try changing `@user = current_user` to `@user = User.where(admin: true).first`

Comment: Still able to get in with an account where admin = false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed up, it routes to the users page, not an index.

Problem solved by changing

```
def index
```

to

```
def users
```

And do the same for the policy method